# "which I use very little" Or "which I use it very little"

Tags: resumptive-pronouns

Should we use the pronoun "it" with "which"? Which one of the following is correct?

> I should sell my car, which I use very little.

Or

> I should sell my car, which I use **it** very little.

Comment: Yes, It is covered what I asked. So, should I remove this question?

Comment: I really don't know if we're better off deleting it or leaving it as a 'signpost' to the other question. That would make an interesting question on [meta].

Comment: @StoneyB I believe the received wisdom is always to leave duplicates where they are and not to delete them.

Comment: @Araucaria I don't get a whole lotta bars on my wisdom receiver.

Comment: @StoneyB I don't get any. I usually use GrapeVine instead ...

Comment: @Araucaria @ StoneyB I don’t get what you’re talking about in last few comments.